# Проблема при обновлении страницы

Tags: meteor

После принудительного обновления страницы перекидывает на форму входа хотя сессия не теряется и данные о пользователе виды из консоли.

router.js

```
Router.map(function() {

  this.route('main', {path: '/'});
  this.route('work', {path: '/work'});
  this.route('/depart', {
  path: '/depart',
  name: 'depart',
  template: 'depart',
  waitOn: function() {
    return [
      Meteor.subscribe('departs')
    ];
  },
  subscriptions: function(){
    return Meteor.subscribe('departs');
  }
});
```

На проблемном шаблоне *main.html* используется проверка залогинен ли пользователь и если нет то показывает шаблон *login*.

```
<template name = "main">
    {{#if currentUser}}
        Main Engine
    {{else}}
    {{> login}}
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

Что может быть? Читал где–то, что якобы при обновлении страницы метеор считает, что это новый сеанс, но почему тогда пользователь остается залогиненым?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в совсем другом, в шаблоне main выводится информация, которая посредством серверного метода метеора и пакета **http** обращается к api стороннего сервиса, что бы отобразить полученную информацию я использовал пакет **reactive-var** который при обновлении станицы выдавал ошибки и приводил к нестабильной работе. Вместо него стал использовать пакет **simple:reactive-method**

```
depart: function () {
    return ReactiveMethod.call('getFdb');
}
```

И все работает стабильно.